# how to encrypt the json data and send using http method in android?

Tags: json, encryption

i want to send my encrypted json data to server using post method in android. This is my code for sending json data. how to encrypt it?

```
public String Update(String userid,String uname)
{
String response = null; 
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();           
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",userid));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status","update"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name",uname));
try
{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL+OPERATION_UPDATE_USERNAME);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));                 
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
response= httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}     
return response.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The encryption must be done in the both sides and the method is depends on what you want from an encryption. For example if you just want to protect your users from man in the middle attacks you could use HTTPS.

Another purpose would be to hide your APIs from hackers to doing this you should define a protocol for yourself, Saying XORing with a static key:

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
String formContent = form.getContent();
String encodedFormContent = "";
char key = 'K';
for (int i = 0; i<formContent.length(); i++) {
    encodedFormContent += formContent.charAt(i) ^ key;
}
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(encodedFormContent));
```

and then decrypt the body in the server side. The XORing method is worst in security but the most simple to mention. You may try AES in practice.

Comment: 1. RC4 is a halfway house between AES and a static key.  2. Encrypted files are byte-data, not text strings.  To make such files transmissible as text strings use Base64 conversion before transmission, and deconvert afterwards of course.

Comment: Do you know that creating additional accounts to vote your own posts up will get you suspended (banned)? That's just cheating.

Comment: I wasn't cheating they are real people and are my friends is that cheating too?

Comment: They weren't your friends but you upvoting your own posts.

Comment: This discussion is not worth continuing at least for me. but they were real people and the reason that you wrongly and deeply believe that they were me is because they use same IP as mine since we are in the same networks most of the times (company and university). though if you could see the mac address they were different (you couldn't for sure). Don't judge too quickly by just seeing logs. not my case but maybe sometimes even two or more people use the same computer and access logs is not that enough to be sure that there were one person or more.